# Condicion ternaria

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo aplicar una condición ternaria en la siguiente línea ?

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TRES", item.respuesta3));
```

Este es su contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de que sea 0 guarde un vacío, de lo contrario todo normal ya que, al seguir me da una exception:

> "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No está del todo claro tu pregunta, creo haberla entendido bien. Te recomiendo que antes de realizar una pregunta la leas en voz alta, y trates de explicarla a otra persona. Eso ayuda a ver si es claro lo que preguntas.

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TRES", item.respuesta3 == 0 ? "" : item.respuesta3));
```

Si necesitas realizar una codicion ternaria, podrías probar en vez de poner la variable, reemplazarla por el condicional.

Hace mucho no programo en C#, espero recordar bien el léxico.

Comment: Creo que haria bien un poco de detalle amigo

Comment: porque le planteas que no esta clara la pregunta, en una respuesta? eso se supone lo debes hacer desde los comentarios antes de aportar una solucion

Comment: Recuersa que las compraciones llevan `==` doble `=`, sino es una asignacion

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias por tu comentario sobre el doble ==, realmente como dije en el mensaje no recordaba el lexico! Ahi lo corrijo.

Comment: Y no puse comentario sobre eso porque no tengo 50 puntos para poder realizar comentarios!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer algo como esto

```
string respuesta3 = item.respuesta3.Count == 0 ? "" : item.respuesta3;
comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TRES", respuesta3));
```

usando el if en linea

[?: operator (C# reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)